# Not able to remove davmail

Tags: davmail

Now I am using 13.04 Ubuntu.I tried to install Davmail I got error message for library missing. After long tries I decided to remove the Davmail.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove davmail
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package davmail needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Same for any application. I cant install or remove the apps
Please Help Me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all davmail
```

If that doesn't work:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/davmail*
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq davmail
```

You should now be `davmail`-free!